# Object in Object return from c++ to node (node addons)

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm trying to return the following structure to node from c++:

```
{
    "hello":"hello there!",
    "obj": {
        "name":"Karl",
        "num":666
    }
}
```

I can't see to include a `Local<Object>` into another `Local<Object>` properly.

Here is the main part of the code:

```
Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello there"));
Local<Object> obj_lvl = Object::New(isolate);
obj_lvl->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "name"),  String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Karl"));
obj_lvl->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "num"),  Integer::New(isolate, 666));
// below here i am trying to include the object "obj_lvl" into the first object "obj"
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "obj"), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, obj_lvl)); // <--- error is here
```

I get the error:

```
../count_node.cc:90:91: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Local<v8::Object>&)’
         obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "obj"), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, obj_lvl));
```

I've been searching for a tutorial but they are either out of date (pre 0.12) or just don't exist. I'm using node version v6.6.0 (npm v3.10.3) and node-gyp version v3.4.0.

Also whats the difference between `Integer::New(isolate, ...));` and `Number::New(isolate, ...));`, been seeing both.

Comment: What are you asking? `NewFromUtf` just doesn't have an overload for a `Local<Object>` as second argument, what's the problem? Please clarify.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Updated! I'm trying to "set" a field in the first object to the second object i created.

Answer (score 0):

Because i had already made a v8 object i just had to apply it as it was:

```
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "obj"), obj_lvl);
```

Working now.